# How to get a 4 containers to display in-line using Bootstrap 3

Tags: twitter-bootstrap-3, inline, col

I have the following Bootstrap markup and and screen shot below. I want the entire group of (4) items to appear in one line and not to break. I've been tweaking for a couple hours and cannot make it happen. Is it possible to get them to all align in 1 row?

```
<div class="container-fluid">
  <div id="sys-page-headerBar-container">
    <div class="row">

      <!--<div class="col-xs-1 col-sm-1 col-md-1 col-lg-1"></div> <!-- left gutter -->

      <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-12 col-md-12 col-lg-12">

<!-- header -->
<form class="form-horizontal" method="post">
<fieldset>

<!-- Text input-->
<div class="form-group">
  <label class="col-md-2 control-label" for="report_date">Service Date(s):</label>
  <div class="col-md-2" id="dispatchLog-container">
    <div class="input-daterange input-group" id="datepicker">
      <input type="text" class="input-sm form-control" name="start" value="<?php echo date( DATE_SZ, strtotime( "today" ) ); ?>" tabindex="1" />
      <span class="input-group-addon">to</span>
      <input type="text" class="input-sm form-control" name="end" value="<?php echo date( DATE_SZ, strtotime( "today" ) ); ?>" tabindex="2" />
    </div>
  </div>
  <label class="col-md-2 control-label" for="report_time">Service Time:</label>
  <div class="input-group bootstrap-timepicker timepicker col-md-1">
    <input id="timepicker" type="text" class="form-control input-small" data-minute-step="30" name="tour_time" tabindex="3"><input type="hidden" id="tour_time_value" value="<?php echo date( DATE_TP, strtotime( "12:00 AM" ) ); ?>">
    <span class="input-group-addon"><i class="glyphicon glyphicon-time"></i></span>
  </div>
  <label class="col-md-1 control-label" for="report_order">Sort Order:</label>
  <div class="col-md-1">
    <select id="report_order" name="report_order" class="form-control" tabindex="4">
    <option></option>
    </select>
  </div>
  <div class="col-md-1">
    <button id="submit" name="submit" class="btn btn-default" value="1" tabindex="5">Go</button>
  </div>
</div>

</fieldset>
</form>

      </div> <!-- .col-xs-10.col-sm-10.col-md-10.col-lg-10 -->

      <!--<div class="col-xs-1 col-sm-1 col-md-1 col-lg-1"></div> <!-- right gutter -->

    </div> <!-- .row -->
  </div> <!-- #sys-login-container -->
</div> <!-- .container-fluid -->
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

One of the things to learn about bootstrap is when to not use bootstrap :-)

In your case just use your own css. 
You can:

- float them all;
- make them all in-line-block
- use flexbox with a fallback for older IE (IE Conditional css) to one of the above methods

Flexbox is probably what I'd use http://caniuse.com/#feat=flexbox, https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/a-guide-to-flexbox/ but inline-block might just do it; In any case you can use your own media queries to change the display format if you need to.